# Roaming and Coming in William Shakespeare's O Mistress Mine

Tags: pronunciation, shakespeare

William Shakespeare's O Mistress Mine, Feste's song from Twelfth Night, seems to have the rhyming scheme AABCCB. However, the first two lines are problematic for that scheme with modern pronunciation:

O Mistress mine, where are you roaming? / O, stay and hear! Your true love's coming,

How is roaming and coming supposed to be pronounced? I suppose the rhyme is intended there!? Recently recording a version I did, I sang with a pronunciation like roaming / "combing" (which may make the song a bit amusing). Should it be "roming" / coming instead? I note that others just ignore the rhyme altogether and sing with modern pronunciation, e.g., [David McCoul's Roger Quilter version](https://youtu.be/ff7lkZt9EeA).

Comment: The rhymes worked in Shakespeare's time because much of English was pronounced very different from nowadays.  David and Ben Crystal put out a CD which recreates many of Shakespeare's most famous parts of his plays in what they feel is the best approximation of OP, or Original Pronunciation.  Well worth listening to.

Comment: I think you can find a lot of it on You Tube too -> https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWm2MsHUHUk6xc4NJm5gqsxZvLgaq1aWW

Answer (score 3):

You really want to open that can of worms here again? No one knows the exact answer; there are approximations. Some people go so far as to claim Shakespeare used sight rhymes (!!), which, of course, is nonsense. Another intriguing theory is that pronunciation in Shakespeare's times was so unstable that a poet, and especially a dramatist, could play fast and loose with it to his heart's content.

Anyway, if you dig a bit deeper into Shakespeare (or any poet up until the middle of the 19th Century, for that matter, even though the Great Vowel Shift was supposed to be long over by then), you'll find dozens of rhymes that are, well, intriguing. To wit:

move/love/cove
blood/good
but/put
war/afar
eye/Italy (my personal favorite)
taste/last (this one comes directly from Shakespeare)
on/groan (ditto)
river/Guadalquiver

and so forth.

Very few people are actually aware of this, and a lot of them tend to get resentful when the problem is pointed out to them.

The same goes for scansion. Three syllables or four? Is ambitious am-bi-shus or am-bi-shuh-es? (in Antony's speech, Julius Caesar, act III, if I recollect aright).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Have you checked out David and Ben Crystals OP work?

Comment: I did not know there was a can of warms. :-) If it is "just" GVS would the first vowel then be somewhere around /ɔː/ and /oː/? I.e., "roming" / coming is better?

Comment: I suspect most of these were true rhymes back then. If you look at Wikipedia's [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) page, it shows lots of changes that happened after 1600. And they also say "The changes that happened after 1600 are not usually considered part of the Great Vowel Shift proper." So vowels kept on shifting (they still are today), but the vowel shifts after 1600 are by definition not the *Great Vowel Shift* but *"post"-Great Vowel Shift*.

Comment: @FinnÅrupNielsen: My guess would be "rohm-ing  /  cohm-ing."

Comment: The only information I see from David and Ben Crystals' website is that "roaming" occurs three times in Shakespeare's works. I see no indication of pronunciation.

Comment: Come on, bro...the school bus is leaving and you're saying you forgot your sweater?  Geesh...http://youtu.be/qYiYd9RcK5M

Comment: It has to be *roaming-coaming*. Otherwise the words would have been spelled *rumming-cumming*. And per the OED, *come* was variously spelled *cum/come/cumme/comme* in Middle English (so both pronunciations existed back then) but *roam* was never spelled with a *"u"*.

Comment: @FinnÅrupNielsen if you find a list of words and how they're pronounced let us know...I have looked and haven't found one.

Comment: @PeterShor: Having researched the matter in some depth, and once again wondering at the aficionado's great difficulties with the phrase "I don't know," I take this opportunity to report that the Great Vowel Shift did NOT, in all likelihood, end in 1600, but went on for at least another two centuries. The vowels kept on shifting merrily up until La Belle Epoque. The problem is some blasted luminary said, at some point in the hoary past, that they had stopped, and no one has had the courage to contradict him since.

Comment: @Ricky. There's a difference between the great vowel shift and language evolving, old sport.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Yes, tiger, I agree. However, if the vowels continued to shift well after 1600, which becomes kind of obvious once you've done even a little bit of research, we might as well admit that we made a mistake earlier, and consider ourselves lucky we're not dealing with French or German. Have you ever heard a German talk about "high German" and "low German" and "Austrian German" and all that shit? It's pretty obvious they don't know anything. It's all a mystery to them. It's also obvious they'll never admit it. "Goethe was the greatest!" Yeah, right.

Comment: I thought "can of warms/worms" was an intended word pun. Now I am sort of disappointed :-)

Comment: @FinnÅrupNielsen: Don't be. You just got a glimpse of my impressionistic spelling. No small potatoes, I assure you.

Comment: Blood/good and but/put are perfect rhymes in my accent, so I'm not sure why you're intrigued by them.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Well. Look them up in a dictionary: see how they're expected to be pronounced.

Comment: @Ricky I suppose it matters who is doing the expecting...

Answer (score 3):

*Roaming* would probably have been pronounced as a monophthong using a close-mid back rounded vowel sound [o:] similar to an extended *no*. *Coming* would have used a close-mid back unrounded vowel, similar to the 'rams horns' [ɤ] similar to *errr*.

This is still not a great rhyme, but maybe closer than in modern pronunciation.

[Hear the sounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA), here [if you can't play .ogg files](http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/),  and a [written discussion here.](http://www.paulmeier.com/OP.pdf)

Comment: No, *roaming* and *coming* might have been an exact rhyme. There were two different pronunciations of *come* in Middle English, as can be seen from the spellings *com/come/comme/cum/cumme* in the OED. The *cumme* pronunciation eventually won, while the *come* spelling won. But I suspect Shakespeare intended the actors to use the pronunciation that rhymed with *roam*.

Comment: There were probably more than two, given that ME is characterised by a high degree of variation. But, bearing in mind that pronunciation of ME is basically speculative, I would need something more substantial than spelling variation listed in the OED to be convinced. Do you have some sources you could share? I would be interested in seeing them if you have.

Comment: While spelling variation in Middle English was enormous,  it generally reflected pronunciation (sometimes the original spelling for foreign words, but *come* isn't foreign); *comme* would not have been spelled with an "o" unless it had been pronounced with an "o" at some time and place—although I don't know whether you can tell if that "o" was short or long. Pupple deedont poot rundam vewls un thur spalling. Why on earth would they have done that?

Comment: Orthography does not map to phonology. Never has and probably never will. It is easy too say "pronounced as an "o", but pronounced by who? People in London, or people in York, or people in Glasgow? Are these the rich, educated people or the poor, uneducated people? Do you think they all pronounced "o" the same way? Asserting that "come" was pronounced two ways because there are two spellings in the OED is not a strong argument.

Comment: That is really splitting hairs. It was pronounced the way that other words with an "o" in their spelling were pronounced, by whoever was doing the spelling and pronouncing. The fact that people in London and York pronounced the vowel in *foam* and *roam* differently doesn't mean that the words didn't rhyme in both cities.

Comment: It s not splitting hairs at all. Language variation is a real thing, well documented, and with its own field of research. This is precisely why you cannot argue that an orthographic "o" in the word means some standard "o" in the pronunciation. I am quite happy to accept variation in Shakespearian pronunciation - I would expect that - but not on the basis of  orthography.

Comment: There is a difference between [lexical sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set) and actual pronunciation, and this difference existed in Middle English as well as Modern English.

Comment: Lexical sets are the *basis* for pronunciation by providing a standard to measure performance against. In my own variety of English, for example, the STRUT set is not pronounced with an /ʌ/ while in London it is  - which illustrates why saying "it is pronounced with "u" because it is spelled with a "u" don't carry much weight. But this is a straw man anyway. I am not saying there was no variation in ME pronunciation. I explicitly said there was. My point is that saying I am wrong because there were two ways to pronounce 'come', based on nothing but an OED spelling list, doesn't fly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32278/discussion-between-peter-shor-and-roaring-fish).